# android - Should I use GLSurfaceView instead of Canvas to avoid bitmapfactory oom?

Tags: android, opengl-es, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory, glsurfaceview

My app needs to load a building floorplan and then draw objects (furniture) on the floorplan.  The floorplan image is a 2500 x 1500 240Kb PNG, but frackin' BitmapFactory crashes most devices by requiring 12+Mb of heap to create the bitmap, giving me an OutOfMemory error.  Let me be clear here: this is not, as far as I can tell, a memory leak, and bitmap.recycle() does nothing because it's crashing while creating the first image, the first time. Reading in the image with inSampleSize doesn't help unless I use a sample size that renders the image unrecognizable.  This whole situation is crazy.  I'm testing on a Droid 3, HTC Inspire, and two 2.3 emulators.  The HTC will load the map, as will the emulator with a (ridiculous) heap size of 128Mb. 
  Deployments of this app will be used across the spectrum of android users, so I can't do anything targeting higher than 2.3 devices.

Here's my current code, which gives me an unusable image (from another SO post, sorry I've lost the link):

```
BitmapFactory.Options o=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, o);


        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=16;
        while((o.outWidth/scale)>=REQUIRED_SIZE || (o.outHeight/scale)>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = scale;

        Bitmap base_image;
        try {
            base_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
        } catch (Error e1) {
            base_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, options);
        }
```

Would a GLSurfaceView solve my problem here? I need it to 1) load the floorplan image, 2) allow me to programatically draw objects and text labels, and 3) support zoom and react to touch based upon floorplan coordinates.  If this is the answer, can anyone recommend a good tutorial for basic 2D work like this?

Comment: Hint: the file size of a PNG means nothing as it is compressed. When used in memory you have (usually) 32 bit or 16 bits (4 or 3 bytes) for each pixel. This means that your 2500 x 1500 image takes 15 megabytes of memory.

Comment: Right, I found that in another question.  How do you recommend I address the situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can decrease memory usage for bitmaps, if you choose to go with openGL you can use pre-compressed textures that you can send directly to the video memory. Android supports ETC1 textures natively, if I remember correctly ETC decreases size with 25%.
However, since you don't have any experience in openGL and also need to do slightly more complex actions such as drawing text this might not be the best action for you (you will probably get the best performance on older devices through this method though). You could consider using any of the engines out there (AndEngine or Box2d are popular).

A faster and possibly better option for you might be to create vector representations (such as `SVG` files) of your floor plans (this should be possible if you have simple plans consisting of a background color and lines for walls). Then draw this using either the [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class or an external library if you want more advanced images.

Comment: I'm obtaining the floorplan files from a third party and I don't think it will be possible to get anything but PNG. I'll look into ETC to see if I can understand/use it.  Thanks.